# Div size = to another div

Tags: javascript, css

I have two divs.  One div contains an image, and the other will contain a text caption that will be layed over the image.

How can I make the caption div width be equal to the image div in a fluid design?

The page is designed using a fluid layout and thus the image will can size with the browser size is changed.

```
<div id="captions">Captions</div>
<div id="image"></div>
```

Is there a way to do this in CSS?

Comment: Wrap them both in a div maybe? So you can control the width...

Comment: why don't you put the text caption in the div as well? like this `<div><img src="" alt=""/><p id="text-caption"></p></div>?`

Answer (score 0):

You could put both elements into your `div` and then set the `width`

```
<div id="yourdiv">
  <img id="yourimg" src="" />
  <p class="yourtext">Here some Text</p>
</div>
```

and then set the width of `.yourtext`

```
.yourtext {
            width: 100%;
          }
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kpauN/2/)

Answer (score 0):

We may inverse the situation as follows:

**HTML**

```
<div id="captions">    
    Captions..
    <div id="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/450/200/" /></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#captions{
    background: #000;
    color:#fff;
   /* width:100%;*/
   display:inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
#image{
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
#image img{
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

[This is a DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/saidbakr/WvgtF/)